# Some troubles with relationsships in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have 2 models with one to many relationships in my .Net Core project:

```
    public class User
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }

            public IEnumerable<Phone> Phone { get; set; }

            public User()
            {
                Phone = new List<Phone>();
            }
        }

    public class Phone
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Number { get; set; }

            public int UserId { get; set; }
            public User User { get; set; }
        }
```

In Api Controller I'm trying to get my users include phones:

```
public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public UserController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<User> Get()
        {
            var users = _db.Users.Include(p => p.Phone).ToArray();
            return users;
        }
}
```

But when I'm trying to call api/user in browser I have this result:

```
[{"id":1,"firstName":"Dima","lastName":"Kirsanov","dateOfBirth":"1999-01-01T00:00:00","phone":[{"id":1,"number":"937-99-92","userId":1
```

So, json array does not include all users  with all their phone numbers

DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new PhoneConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserConfiguration());


            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

And Fluent Api configuration:

```
public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
    {
        public void Configure (EntityTypeBuilder<User> user)
        {
            user.HasKey(u => u.Id);

            user.HasMany(u => u.Phone)
                .WithOne(p => p.User)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId);



            user.Property(u => u.FirstName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            user.Property(u => u.LastName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

        }
    }

public class PhoneConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Phone>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Phone> phone)
        {
            phone.HasKey(p => p.Id);

            phone.Property(p => p.Number)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(30);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add your DbContext configuration

Comment: Include means eager loading. So you will get all the phone numbers that are related to that specific user, not all users?!

Comment: In my DB i have 4 users and each user have 2 phone numbers. So how can I get all users with all their phone numbers?

Comment: Cant see anything obviously wrong - try debugging the API and testing what `_db.Users.ToList()` evaluates to. Perhaps there is a problem in your data.

Comment: Is that the whole json result? Seems like its cut off at the end.

Comment: Yes, it is the whole json result...

Comment: In the Postman I could not get any response from api/user

Comment: Check your database to make your use all data you are talking about here are there.

Comment: changing from `IEnumerable<Phone>` to `ICollection<Phone>` may solve the problem

Comment: Change `IEnumerable<Phone> Phone` to `List<Phone> Phone`. Check in debugger what does `users` hold. **Tip 1**: Pluralize collection properties (`Phone` should be `Phones`). **Tip 2**: Try first to use attribute configurations for not to jump from configurations to classes. This really irritates.